# clang code completion - implementation design

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, llvm, code-completion

Is there some hidden documentation how the code-completion part of clang is implemented? What i've found out so far is that a special token (tok::code_completion) gets injected into the lexer and is handled in the parser. After observing such a token the parser can fill in possible completion strings.

What I don't understand:
If the called functionality decides that we can insert a variable which is available in the current context. How is such a case handled?

```
struct FooBar {
    void foo() {
        ba<<code completion here>>
    }
    void bar() {
    }
};
```

The parser hasn't seen bar but it's valid to call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I see it, this is a general problem when parsing method definitions inside a struct, and is not specific to code completion. In any case, there's special handling in the parser precisely for this case, which you can find in [the ParseCXXInlineMethods.cpp file](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ParseCXXInlineMethods_8cpp-source.html).

From the comment on `Parser::ParseCXXInlineMethodDef()`:

```
/// ParseCXXInlineMethodDef - We parsed and verified that the specified
/// Declarator is a well formed C++ inline method definition. Now lex its body
/// and store its tokens for parsing after the C++ class is complete.
Parser::DeclPtrTy
Parser::ParseCXXInlineMethodDef(...
```

And later, code for parsing the method  definitions:

```
/// ParseLexedMethodDefs - We finished parsing the member specification of a top
/// (non-nested) C++ class. Now go over the stack of lexed methods that were
/// collected during its parsing and parse them all.
void Parser::ParseLexedMethodDefs(...
```

Thus the lexer-generated tokens for the function bodies are only parsed after the rest of the class was parsed.